# How to solve this error in android studio?

Tags: android, gradle

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
>   org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command
>   '/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit
>   value 3

my Gradle File

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.techkrish.studio.f1desk"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile project(path: ':backend', configuration: 'android-endpoints')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.1.0'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.3.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'org.apache.karaf.http:http:3.0.5'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-api-1.0-sdk:1.9.18'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

- Open system task manager and kill the java process gradle is running in
- Build > Rebuild